# Oracle: transfer data between two database without db link

Tags: oracle, toad

I've got two database on different network. They can't see each other. So I can't use a Db Link.

Does toad or any other tool allow me to copy data from one db to the other one simulating a db link (it would be really simple simply executing a select on first DB and an insert on the second DB).

Comment: Anything solution for DataGrip or any JetBrains IDEA with Database connection support?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toad can do it easily - instructions are for ver 11. First, connect to both databases using Toad. Then, find the table(s) in question in the Schema Browser. Right click on the table name, click 'Copy Data to Another Schema'. Choose the correct source/destination schemas, and set the options for the copy (triggers/constraints enable/disable, etc). Then click the green Play button and watch the records fly!

Answer (score 5):

If your workstation can see both databases simultaneously, you might be able to use the [Database Copy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/doc.112/e12152/dialogs.htm#BACDECCG) tool in SQL Developer

SQL*PLus also has a [Copy command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/apb.htm).

Answer (score 2):

Toad or any other client is not a good solution for big tables, the client PC may fail or slow down, the network link may not be enough reliable, or the bandwith not enough.
I would recommend Oracle Data Pump (expdp,impdp) in Oracle 10 onwards, or the former tools (exp/imp), sqlloader, etc. if we are talking of large environments.

Answer (score 1):

Dump a text file, FTP or move it, and then use SQL*Loader on the other side?

Answer (score 1):

Export from Source DB and then Import into Target DB