# No records when using SELECT query on DBLINK in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad, dblink

I'm trying to move data in between two oracle databases say SOURCE_A and DEST_B. I have created a dblink (LINK_A) using TOAD on DEST_B to SOURCE_A to copy data from the tables. Dblink creation was fine, but when I used a select statement like below, I see no data except column names.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A@LINK_A;
```

Could you please help me understand what am I doing wrong or missing here. I tried running a DESC on the TABLE_A using the link and it worked fine. Not sure why its not pulling any data from the SOURCE_A database.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Not offensive and I didn't mean to shout at any one. Am looking for someone who can help me here. Can you pls help me if you know what should be done to solve my issue here.

Comment: At a guess you link is defined with the wrong user or to the wrong database, but just speculating really. What you have should work if everything is defined correctly.

Comment: Try SELECT name FROM v$database@link_a;  to see what the database name you're connecting to actually is.

Comment: You can use SELECT sys_context@link_a('USERENV','CURRENT_USER') FROM dual; to see who the logged in user is on the remote database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, with many trial and errors, I managed to get a solution that works for me in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818085/oracle-transfer-data-between-two-database-without-db-link).

I used the technique provided by - Jeremy Scoggins and it worked like charm. I was able to move data using toad and its perfect. Thanks to all of you for your time and support.

Appreciate it.